# Не сохраняеться обьект класса Cart нужно реализовать связь has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 user1 = User.create(login: "serge")
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("login", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["login", "serge"], ["created_at", 2017-02-12 16:12:24 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-02-12 16:12:24 UTC]]
   (180.3ms)  commit transaction
 => # 
2.3.3 :005 > cart1 = Cart.create
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => # 
2.3.3 :006 > cart1 = Cart.create!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist
```

```
class CreateCartsItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :carts_items, id: false do |t|
      t.references :cart
      t.references :item
    end
    add_index :carts_items, [:item_id, :cart_id]
    add_index :carts_items, [:cart_id, :item_id]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :carts_items
  end

end

class Cart < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to              :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :items

  # validates               :user
  # validates               :user_id
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :description, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0, allow_nil: true }

  has_and_belongs_to_many :carts
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Зачем тебе сохранять пустую корзину в базе. Лучше вызвать метод Cart.new и прикреплять к ней User и Items затем сохранить через save. Вообще книжка агил веб девелопмент(есть перевод на русском или напиши мне скину) для тебя, там подробно рассматривают создание магазина.

Пример для контроллера(необходимо реализовать правильные связи и метод current_user) :

cart1 = Cart.new

cart1.user_id = current_user.id

cart1.save

cart.save

Писать нам надо много для тебя, не знаю что написать, лучше пройди книгу....

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.